# Warning: missing space before text for line 21 of jade file

Tags: html, node.js, gulp, pug

I am getting these warnings in the terminal once I run `$ gulp build`:

```
Warning: missing space before text for line 21 of jade file "/Users/berretan/Documents/Projects/cms-fe/assets/partials/components/drivers-guide/masthead-drivers-guide.jade"
Warning: missing space before text for line 26 of jade file "/Users/berretan/Documents/Projects/cms-fe/assets/partials/components/drivers-guide/masthead-drivers-guide.jade"
Warning: missing space before text for line 31 of jade file "/Users/berretan/Documents/Projects/cms-fe/assets/partials/components/drivers-guide/masthead-drivers-guide.jade"
```

Here are the parts of the code where the errors comes:

```
.slide
    .vertical-center-section
        h1 Fuel is Always in Season
        p At BP, the gas you fill up in the winter is different than the gas you'll pump in the summer. See, you do learn something new everyday.
        a(href="#" class="btn opacity yellow_to_green") Find Out Why
.slide
    .vertical-center-section
        h1 Fuel is Always in Season
        p At BP, the gas you fill up in the winter is different than the gas you'll pump in the summer. See, you do learn something new everyday.
        a(href="#" class="btn opacity yellow_to_green") Find Out Why
.slide
    .vertical-center-section
        h1 Fuel is Always in Season
        p At BP, the gas you fill up in the winter is different than the gas you'll pump in the summer. See, you do learn something new everyday.
        a(href="#" class="btn opacity yellow_to_green") Find Out Why
.slide
    .vertical-center-section
        h1 Fuel is Always in Season
        p At BP, the gas you fill up in the winter is different than the gas you'll pump in the summer. See, you do learn something new everyday.
        a(href="#" class="btn opacity yellow_to_green") Find Out Why
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a large text at `p`, try putting a `|` pipe before the text:

```
.slide
    .vertical-center-section
        h1 Fuel is Always in Season
        p 
          |At BP, the gas you fill up in the winter is different than the     gas you'll pump in the summer. See, you do learn something new everyday.
        a(href="#" class="btn opacity yellow_to_green") Find Out Why
```

Source: http://learnjade.com/tour/tags-and-text/